# why HTML form is not displaying in outlook email client?

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, outlook-2007, outlook

below is my google apps script to display HTML form in the mail to the client and fetching response via web-service. this works fine when my client is using Gmail account and form is displaying perfectly nice and also all the events are working correctly. but the problem occurs when my client tries this same with outlook account the `<textarea>`, `<button>` (these tags are not displaying). Can anyone tell me what's the problem? for outlook account is there any more settings we need to do?

```
function sendAutoReply(e)
{
  var myemail = "viral.shah@searce.com";
  var email = "";
  var subject = "Your Request Status Message.."; 
  var html = 
      '<body>' + 
      '<table border="1">'+
      '<tr>'+
      '<td>'+
      '<label>  Comment </label>'+'<br>'+'<br>'+
      '</td>'+
      '</tr>'+
      '<tr>'+
      '<td>'+
      '<textarea rows="5" cols="100"/>'+'<br>'+'<br>'+
      '</td>'+
      '</tr>'+
      '<tr>'+
      '<td>'+
      '<input type="button" value="accept"/>'  +
      '</td>'+
      '<td>'+
      '<input type = "button" value = "Decline"/>'+
      '</td>'+
      '</tr>'+
      '</table>'+
      '</body>';

  try {  
    for(var field in e.namedValues) {

      if (field == 'Subject') {
        subject += e.namedValues[field].toString();
      }
      if (field == 'Email') {
        email = e.namedValues[field].toString();
      }
      html += field + ' : '
        + e.namedValues[field].toString() + "\n\n";
    }   
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, html, {replyTo:myemail, htmlBody:html});
 }
catch(e){
   MailApp.sendEmail(myemail, "Error in Auto replying to contact form submission. No reply was sent.", e.html);
 }
}
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I'm telling it won't support any HTML tags into outlook email client

Please Go through this  [Forum Link](http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f30/designing-html-emails-outlook-2007-a-20920/)

And this  [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

I think these articles will make clear thoughts about this.

Answer (score 4):

Outlook doesn't support the `<button>` tag:

[The HTML tags that Outlook supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Try using `<input type="button">` instead of  and it should work.

As for `<textarea>`, it's technically supported, but there appear to be lots of people who complain about it not working. That document says in one place that it supports the "cols" attribute and in another place that it does not, so try removing that perhaps. Also, Outlook is finicky enough about HTML that I'd try explicit closing tags like `<textarea></textarea>` instead of the shorthand style.

Comment: is there not any other way to make forms in `pdf format` or `Google apps UI script` through ?

Comment: UiApp will not work in HTML forms. You can generate PDFs in Apps Script, but I can't think of any way to generate one with an embedded form.

Comment: The limitation here is largely what Outlook supports (not full HTML) and not as much what Apps Script lets you email (anything you like).

Answer (score 0):

for outlook 2007 mail client  [not displaying forms there](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2435/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/). so, this one is not possible in outlook mail client. check the given link.

Hope this one helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If the button action is simple enough that can be equivalent to visiting an url, you can add a message like the following:

> Confirm email through this link if confirm button is unavailable
>   https://www.example.com/confirm/av87hfua7ImAToken4vf8a98jao5ia

Those who see the button will also see this sentence, but since this is a fairly common practice it won't cause much noise.